# Error handling with ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, infura, async

I've got a getContract function that looks something like this.

```
const getContract = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(process.env.NETWORKS, process.env.ENDPOINT_KEY);
    let wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(process.env.MNEMONIC);

    const isReady = await provider.ready;
    

    if(isReady){
      wallet = wallet.connect(provider);
    
      const contractAddress = WakandaVotingPlatform.networks["4"].address;

      return new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, WakandaVotingPlatform.abi, wallet);   
    }

    console.log(isReady);
    
}
```

My goal is to check if provider is ready to do it's job, and if for some reason it's not (the internet is down) I want to return something else instead of the contract, but this just doesn't seem to work. What would be the proper way to handle such error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe call a cheaper ethereum method.

> provider.getNetwork();